# How to display tabs of AutoTabsRouter.tabBar conditionally on Flutter using auto_route

Tags: flutter, tabbar

Is it possible to choose the tabs of a TabBar based on a condition? When I do it like the following, the router does not navigate to the other tabs (I still get the NavigationObserver messages on the console). If I choose a `Visibility` widget to wrap the Tabs, there is a space on the `TabBar`. Also, I actually am able to navigate between the tabs by swiping. Tapping on the TabBar items does not work.

I shared the same question [on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1345) as well.

Routes:

```dart
 return AutoTabsRouter.tabBar(
            routes: [
              ARoute(),
              if ((conditionB)
                BRoute(),
              if (conditionC)
                CRoute(),
              DRoute(),
            ],
            builder: (context, child, controller) {
```

Tabs:

```dart
return TabBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    tabs: <Widget>[
                      const Tab(text: 'A'),
                      if (conditionB)
                      const Tab(text: 'B'),
                      if (conditionC)
                      const Tab(text: 'C'),
                      const Tab(text: 'D'),
                    ],
```

NavigationObserver outputs:

```
flutter: Tab route re-visited: BRoute
flutter: Previous route: ARoute
flutter: Tab route re-visited: CRoute
flutter: Previous route: BRoute
```